# How can I set discount in price at product order by a customer programmatically

Tags: magento2, cart, discount

If a customer places an order for 5 Qty of a product, then a 10% discount would be given.

How can I do in Magento2 programmatically

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new module (if you haven't already) in the **`app/code`** directory of your Magento 2 installation.
2. Create a new **`di.xml`** file in the etc directory of your module, and register a plugin for the **`\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem`** class.
3. In the plugin class, use the **`afterConvert`** method to set the discount on the price of the product.

Here is an example of how the plugin class might look:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class QuoteItem
{
    public function afterConvert(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem $subject,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item $orderItem
    ) {
        $orderItem->setDiscountAmount(10);
        $orderItem->setBaseDiscountAmount(10);
        return $orderItem;
    }
}
```

In this example, the discount amount is set to 10 for both the discount amount and the base discount amount. You can adjust the value as you need.

Please keep in mind that this is just an example, and you may need to adjust it to match the requirements of your specific use case.

Let me know if any query.

**`THANKS.`**